# How to set silent notifications for specific token?

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging, with Cordova.
I want to allow the user to set silent notifications in the app settings.

However, I often push notifications to the whole topic subscribers and therefore I cannot set it silent for specific users.

I think that the correct approach is to send an http request to the fcm servers and tell them that this particular token should receive silent notifications. If this is the right approach.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
In Service:-
token='key=AAAA7SRV_tKJ1NzRT8d2VJ5NGkayEx1HT9SxrdTT5G5a4kx5c6GoDvmWmzhCTWDRCqrdACrctF5Gjy5Df2qf6ZCNJHt7oHfH7BC'

createNotification(data) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': this.token
    });
    console.log('Res from Frontend=>', data)
    return this.http.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', data, { headers: headers }).subscribe(res => {
      console.log('Res from APi', res)
    })

  }


In component.ts:-
const fcm = {
        "notification": {
          "title": '',
          "body": '',
          "sound": "default",
          "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
          "icon": "./../../assets/images/logos/arabic-purpal-logo.png"
        },
        "data": {
          "hello": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messagin  hbhj g Device Gr new v Message!",
        },
        "to": 'FCM Token Here'
      };
      this.service.createNotification(fcm)
    }
Note:- Put the token in string, it send only for that user only
```